# How to refresh JwtBearer scheme metadata from discovery endpoint before application is started or just after it started?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

Authentication with JwtBearer is configured as follows:

```cs
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Configuring options");

        options.MetadataAddress = settings.DiscoveryUrl;
        options.AutomaticRefreshInterval = TimeSpan.FromHours(24);
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuer = settings.Issuer,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudience = settings.Audience,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
        };
    });

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

// ...

var app = builder.Build();

// ...

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

// ...
```

However, when application is started nothing is logged into console until first request is is sent to the app. No idea why authentication is not configured right away. The problem is that this means that metadata from discovery endpoint are fetched on first request, and because of this first request is very slow (takes like 3-5 sec). Further requests take like 100ms.

So my question is how to manually request metadata to be downloaded (and authentication scheme configured) either before application is started or just after it's started?

I tried adding following code just before application is started:

```cs
app.Lifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(() =>
{
    var cfgManager = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>>();
    cfgManager.RequestRefresh();
});
```

But it throws

```
No service for type 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.IConfigurationManager`1[Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfiguration]' has been registered.`
```

I guess this is because for some reason this authentication scheme is configured after first request that uses this scheme...

Comment: Both of these lines `app.UseAuthentication();` and `app.UseAuthorization();` are before `app.MapControllers();`?

Comment: I don't use any controllers, just GraphQL so after `builder.build()` I have only: app.UseAuthentication(), app.UseAuthorization(), app.UseGraphQL(...) in this order. GraphQL is from GraphQL.Server.Transports.AspNetCore package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you add registration for `IConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>` ? Cuz `AddJwtBearer()` wont do that for you.

First you need to provide `IConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>` to your `JwtBearerOptions` something like this :

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
    {
        var configManager = new 
         ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(
         settings.DiscoveryUrl,
         new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever());
        Console.WriteLine("Configuring options");

        options.MetadataAddress = settings.DiscoveryUrl //You can remove this now since you have Configuration manager;
        opt.ConfigurationManager = configManager;
        options.AutomaticRefreshInterval = TimeSpan.FromHours(24);
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuer = settings.Issuer,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudience = settings.Audience,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
        };
    });
```

After that you can get the `JwtBearerOptions` like this:
UPDATE (thanks to the @user606521)

```
        var app = builder.Build(); 
        using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope()) 
        { 
          scope.ServiceProvider
         .GetRequiredService<IOptionsSnapshot<JwtBearerOptions>>().Get("Bearer")
         .ConfigurationManager!
         .GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken.None); 
         }
```

Comment: It did not work, because JwtBearerOptions are "named" options and therefore could not be loaded through `IOptions<JwtBearerOptions>`. Also `RequestRefresh()` does not actually make any request, it does only mark configuration to be refreshed. But it was good direction I ended up with:`
var app = builder.Build();
        
        using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptionsSnapshot<JwtBearerOptions>>().Get("Bearer")
                .ConfigurationManager!.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken.None);
        }`

Comment: Please update your answer with my comments above and I will accept it (Options has to be accessed through IOptionsSnapshot and also GetConfigurationAsync has to be used instead of RequestRefresh

Comment: Hi @user606521 - thanks for the update. I have updated my answer and I'm glad that I pointed you in right direction. Best of luck!